# How to restructure/design the following code of custom Cmdlet? Within callstack, from any place to know the executing cmd?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, powershell

Basically i have my own custom Cmdlet. At any given point of time within a call stack, i would like to know the Cmdlet thats been executed by the PowerShell Command Processor without passing the Cmd.  Since its a relatively big assembly (PSModule) with so many custom cmdlets (>=160) and utility methods i would like to have a centralized or generic way to know the current executing Cmd.

Please see the below code, that probably explains the problem in better.

Using a gloabl (static) variable and setting it while Cmdlet being instantiated probably or at the time of BeginProcessing, but it will have side effects if the more than 1 cmd has been executed simulataneouly, saying probably using PowerShell job's infrastructure as its global variable one of them will replace it.

Looks like i need to have context info (mostly the thread on which Cmdlet has been instantiated, but dont know how to strcuture it). Can anyone please give me some ideas?

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Psudeo code to depict the problem
    /// </summary>
    class MyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        public MyCmdlet()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It doesnt seem right
        /// For ex, if two of my cmdslets are instantiated (probably by say, Start-Job)
        /// </summary>
        internal static MyCmdlet ExecutingCmdInstance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
            //it will have side effects if more than one Cmdlet has been executed by start-job.
            //as executing cmd instance will replaced by last Cmdlet thats been run by job.
            ExecutingCmdInstance = this;
        }

        private void foo()
        {
            MyCmdlet cmdlet = null;//How do i know which Cmdlet is being executing without passing Cmdlet?
            Class1.foo(this /*I dont want to pass it as the parameter needs to be passed around in so many places*/);
        }
    }

    internal static class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// I dont want to pass MyCmdlet with each invocation 
        /// Is there a better way the Cmdlet thats been currently executing
        /// (within which cmdlet execution context the cmd is running?)
        /// Say, for ex: asking powershell engine or some other way?
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="IDontWantToPassit"></param>
        static internal void foo(MyCmdlet IDontWantToPassit)
        {
            MyCmdlet cmdlet = null;//How do i know which Cmdlet is being executing without passing Cmdlet?
        }
    }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PowerShell exposes any way to get what you're asking for.

One possibility is to keep a static Stack.  In each of your BeginProcessing/ProcessRecord/EndProcessing methods, you would wrap the body like this:

```
try {
    stack.Push(this);    
    // regular body
} finally {
    stack.Pop();
}
```

Then you can just peek at the stack to see which cmdlet is on top.  You can probably avoid wrapping the body if your cmdlet doesn't write any objects or otherwise call out to code that you need this information.

Comment: thnaks for the reply. Ya, it looks like PowerShell wont exposes it. Using global stack is some what similar to using static instance only. the probably is if more than one Cmdlet is executed in parallel (say for ex, using jobs) then there is way to know which the Cmdlet code in callstack reference. but, i can use something like Dictionary<ThreadIdOnWithBeginProcessing, MyCmdlet> i guess...

Comment: At stack is pretty much required.  A call to WriteObject from one cmdlet can end up calling ProcessRecord in another cmdlet that is downstream in the pipeline.  Thread local storage is better than a global and simpler than a dictionary.

Comment: It works in case of pipeline. What about when two cmds are executed in parallel? thats why i am planning to use global dictionary which maps thread id on which processing (begin, end, process...) methods executed and the Cmdlet. So, at any given point of time i can get to the Cmdlet...

Comment: Right - you need a stack per thread/thread id.  A dictionary with a key of thread id is just like thread local storage but slower.